# How do I change the View module in Conn from a controller?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a function in my CustomerEvents controller as follows:

```
  def index(conn, params) do
    list = CustomerEvents.list_customer_events(params)

    conn |> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView)

    render(conn, "index.json", customers: list)
    end
  end
```

For this particular function the result from `list_customer_events` needs to go to my `CustomersView`, not the `CustomerEvents` view it tries to use by default.

From reading the documentation  I thought that `conn |> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView)` would be enough to make that change but it doesn't seem to make any difference. When inspecting the conn object I still see:

`:phoenix_view => MyApp.CustomerEventView` in the `private` map. with my current understanding I would expect it to be `:phoenix_view => MyApp.CustomerView`.

How do I make this kind of change correctly?

Comment: It worked when I changed it to `conn |> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView |> render("index.json", customers: list)` but I'm not entirely sure why. I'd have thought maybe an assignment issue but  I had tried it with `conn = conn|>put_view()` previously and it didnt work. If someone could expand on the difference I'd be grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't pipe the `conn` correctly:

```
conn |> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView)
render(conn, "index.json", customers: list)
```

All functions in elixir return a new value, meaning that when you use `conn |> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView)` you get a new `conn`, however you send to render the old one.

To render the correct view, you either pipe everything or send the updated value:

```
updated_conn = conn |> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView)
render(updated_conn, "index.json", customers: list)
```

or

```
conn 
|> put_view(MyApp.CustomersView)
|> render("index.json", customers: list)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something fundamental I was doing wrong.